# HeidiSQL script for importing csv files to MySQL database

Tags: shell, heidisql

I am with a Linux OS machine and I was wandering if there is an option for importing new files every x minutes into my database (MySQL).

I mean, I receive new files in a directory every x minutes and I know that with HeidiSQL I can import CSV files manually. However, I would like it to be automatic and periodically with a scrpit in my Linux machine. I was thinking about using cron to repetively doing the action, I only do not know if there is a command which imports files to HeidiSQL.

I tried to find it in the Heidi Webpage but it seems there is no information about it.I am also open to other suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot import files into HeidiSQL. Instead, you want to import CSV files into your MySQL/MariaDB server. HeidiSQL is a client for these servers.

Then, HeidiSQL cannot do much scheduled stuff, as it's a graphical client and as such provides only very few command line parameters, which are [documented](http://www.heidisql.com/help.php#commandline).

But you can use the mysql(.exe on Windows) command line program to do that. Just an example:

```
path/to/mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -pwhatever --database=yourdb --execute="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/to/your/file.csv' INTO TABLE `foo` CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (`fooid`, `foosubid`, `fooname`)"
```